# CloudFormation change windows computer name

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to add the Rename-Computer line into a CloudFormation script but it is not doing anything, I know that I have to use the UserData property inside the resource stage, I see some examples and also the AWS CloudFormation documentation, but I think I'm missing something, in the examples, they just invoke the PowerShell command (As I did below) and it works, but for me is not doing anything, can someone help me with this? If anyone has a better example that it is already working I will appreciate it.

```
  "Resources" : {
    "EC2InstanceOne":{
      "Type":"AWS::EC2::Instance",
      "DeletionPolicy" : "Retain",
      "Properties":{
        "InstanceType":{ "Ref" : "InstanceType" },
        "SubnetId": { "Ref" : "MySubnetVM1" },
        "SecurityGroupIds":[ { "Ref" : "SGUtilized" } ],
        "SecurityGroupIds":[ { "Ref" : "SGUtilized2" } ],
        "IamInstanceProfile"  : { "Ref" : "RoleName" },
        "KeyName": { "Ref" : "ServerKeyName" },
        "ImageId":{ "Ref" : "AMIUtilized" },
        "BlockDeviceMappings" : [
               {
                  "DeviceName" : "/dev/sda1",
                  "Ebs" : {
                     "VolumeType" : "standard",
                     "DeleteOnTermination" : "false",
                     "VolumeSize" : "50"
                  }
               }
            ],
                "UserData" : { "Fn::Base64" : { "Fn::Join" : [ "", [
                        "powershell.exe Rename-Computer -NewName TESTVM01",
                        "powershell.exe Restart-Computer"
                ]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Thanks, best regards.

Comment: Could it be that I have to add them between<powershell>?

 [
                        "<powershell>\n",
                            "powershell.exe Rename-Computer -NewName TESTVM01",
                         "powershell.exe Restart-Computer",
                        "</powershell>"
                    ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix it replacing the PowerShell part with the following parameters

```
"<script>\n",
"PowerShell -Command \"& {Rename-Computer -NewName testvm01}\" \n",
"PowerShell -Command \"& {Restart-Computer}\" \n",
"</script>"
```